# Selecting multiple check edit boxes in a grid control

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm trying selecting multiple check edit boxes when added as a repository item in a grid control, but at the moment it only allows me to select one at a time. So far I've seen that one need to unbound the checkedit's. But I don't know how to do this.

Does anyone have good examples or links of how I can get this working.

Because what I need to do is select certain option in the beginning of a process and then late display the exact same selections but still with the unselected ones

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are asking about is the default one for XtraGrid, DXGrid (WPF).  I believe that you are using XtraGrid and do not understand the problem you ran into.  Everything should work properly and should not require additional adjustments.  Could you please explain the problem in greater details.  If the XtraGrid does not allow the end-user to edit its data, we need to know which DataSource you are using.

Comment: Hi, I'm using DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl in a normal view not WPF. My problem is when I add a new column to the grid and select CheckEdit as a new repository item under the ColumnEdit property, application then only allows me make one selection in the check boxes. When I select another one it deselect the previous one. I hope this makes more sense

Comment: You should set the column's FieldName property to resolve this problem.  Or make this column unbound.  The latter option looks to be the best for you.  To learn how this can be done, please refer to the "Unbound columns" topic available at: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477

Comment: Do you maybe have nay code examples of how the it should be done inside the gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnDataand also the repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged. I've been trying a few things but no success as of yet. Thanks